# AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute 'get_height'

Tags: python

Should you need it, the tutorial I am following is Python Programming by #Derek Banas:

This lesson is demonstrating class object inheritance

```
class Animal:
     __name = ""
     __height = 0
     __weight = 0
     __sound = 0

     def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):         
         self.__name = name
         self.__height = height
         self.__weight = weight 
         self.__sound = sound

     def set_name(self, name):
         self.__name = name

     def get_name(self):
         return self.__name

     def get_type(self):
         print("Animal")

     def toString(self):
         return "{} is {} cm tall and {} kilograms and {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                  self.__height,
                                                                  self.__weight,
                                                                  self.__sound)

cat = Animal('Whiskers', 33, 10, 'Meow')
print(cat.toString())

class Dog(Animal):
     __owner = ""

     def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner): 
         self.__owner = owner        
         super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

     def set_owner(self, owner):
         self.__owner = owner

     def get_owner(self):
         return self.__owner

     def get_type(self):
         print("Dog")

     def toString(self):
         return "{} is {} cm tall & {} kgrms and {} hi                                                        
                       {}".format(self.get_name(),                                                                  
                                                    self.get_height(),

                                                    self.get_weight(),

                                                    self.get_sound(),

                                                    self.get_owner())
```

""" I am getting this runtime error message python version 3.6

Here is the error:

```
File "C:/Watson/HDM/tutorial_py1.py", line 192, in toString
    self.get_height(),

AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute 'get_height' """
```

Comment: Go ahead and define your ```get_height``` in ```Dog``` or in the ```Animal```

Comment: As well as `get_weight` and `get_sound` otherwise it will throw an error again.

Answer (score 2):

Dog object is not having any attribute 'get_height' as get_height() function is not declared in the class before. You need to add the method in the class:

```
def get_height(self, name):
     return self.__height
```